# Добавить в DataFlavor собственный класс (Drag and Drop Java)

Tags: java, swing, drag-n-drop

Я пытаюсь добавить в dataFlavor свой класс (Item.class), чтобы передать его при помощи drag and drop

```
@Override
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {                
    DataFlavor itemFlavor = new DataFlavor(Item.class, Item.class.getSimpleName());               
    try{
        System.out.println(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(itemFlavor));
    }catch(UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Item.class

```
public class Item {
    private String classFile;
    private String imgFile;
    private String imgPath;    

    public Item(String classFile, String imgFile, String imgPath){
        this.classFile = classFile;
        this.imgFile = imgFile;
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }

    public String getImgFile() {
        return imgFile;
    }

    public void setImgFile(String imgFile) {
        this.imgFile = imgFile;
    }   

    public String getClassFile() {
        return classFile;
    }

    public void setClassFile(String classFile) {
        this.classFile = classFile;
    }

    public String getImgPath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    public void setImgPath(String imgPath) {
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }
}
```

но я получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке: `java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Item`

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку ?**

Я использовал следующую документацию https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html

Пример, который демонстрирует проблему [DND Test Project](https://github.com/NickEnbachtov/DNDProject) . Можете его скачать, поместить эти классы в проект и запустить.

Для того чтобы получить ошибку, перетащите объект из JTable на JLayeredPane

Comment: Что должен делать твой код? Если перетаскивать элементы из таблицы на панель, зачем ты добавляешь drop в таблицу и drag в лейбл? Таблица должна реализовать drag, а лейбл вообще не нужен, если ты его в панели создаешь. Потом, тебе нужно создать Transferable класс для твоих объектов Item и добавить его в Drag Listener для таблицы.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала кратко напишу, как работает Drag&Drop. Есть объект **DragSource**, который отвечает за операцию Drag, и объект **DropTarget**, который отвечает за операцию Drop. Эти объекты должны быть привязаны к соответствующим компонентам. Сам перетаскиваемый объект (в твоем случае **Item**) инкапсулируется внутрь объекта, который реализует интерфейс **Transferable**. Тип перетаскиваемого объекта определяет **DataFlavor**.

1) Создаем класс **ItemTransferable**, DataFlavor засунем туда же:

```
public class ItemTransferable implements Transferable {
    public final static DataFlavor ITEM_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(Item.class, Item.class.getSimpleName());
    private Item item;

    public ItemTransferable(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[] { ITEM_FLAVOR };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return ITEM_FLAVOR.equals(flavor);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (flavor.equals(ITEM_FLAVOR))
            return item;
        else
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
    }
}
```

2) Создадим Drag Listener для таблицы:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Item[][] { { new Item("class_1", "image_1", "path_1") },
                    { new Item("class_2", "image_2", "path_2") }, { new Item("class_3", "image_3", "path_3") },
                    { new Item("class_4", "image_4", "path_4") }, { new Item("class_5", "image_5", "path_5") } },
                    new String[] { "Column Name" }));
DragSource ds = new DragSource();
ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(table, DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, new DragGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            Item item = (Item) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            dge.startDrag(null, new ItemTransferable(item));
        }
    }
});
```

3) В методe drop():

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(ItemTransferable.ITEM_FLAVOR).toString());
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
```

Еще можно сделать через **TransferHandle** - это вроде более высокоурневый способ, но я никогда с этим не разбирался. Вообще, drag&drop - это адский геморрой, и я бы его избегал любыми способами.

Comment: Согласен, на Java очень сложно реализовать drag&drop с собственным типом перетаскиваемого объекта, т.к. примеры в основном со стринговым типом или файлы и многое в документации не до конца объясняют, но все-таки  интересно реализовать.